# Can we Programatically change Dfc.properties File in composer Dynamically

Tags: java, dql, documentum, dfc

I have written a Java(Documentum) Programme where we need to change DocBase repeateadly, 
Is there any way we can change dfc.properties based on some condition? 
Changes are like commenting one Line ie the Docbase propert while uncommenting otehr tahts all, but it should be dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two session based on some condition or even three docbase.
see this blog.
http://documentumknowledge.blogspot.com/2011/08/how-to-create-two-session-to-two.html